# Why promise go to other promise on unreturned value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to loop between several Promise and quit the sequence when a if statement is not validated, without throwing an error (reject).

Look at the code below :

```
return formRef.current.isValid()
            .then((isValid) => {
                if (isValid) {
                    return formatAndCreateUser(account);
                }
            })
            .then(createResponse => {
                createdUser = createResponse;
                return userApi.requestToken({email: account.email, password: account.password});
            })
```

Here, even if the `isValid` variable if false, it will go through the second promise. It's not what i wanted... I would like to go the `formatAndCreateUser` function is the `isValid` is true, else do nothing...

Comment: why do you not want to throw an error. doing that will prevent the second the then from running, which seems to be what you want

Comment: So either move the second `.then()` behind `formatAndCreateUser(account)` or switch to `async` and `await` and use basic "synchronous" `if` code. I guess you can also use `else return Promise.reject` maybe? That should trigger a potential catch block.

Comment: Because my catch statement is only for unhandled error.. Here, it's just my form validation didn't passed

Comment: if (!createResponse) justDoNothing

Answer (score 3):

You should throw an error, and then handle it. If you want, the handler can just be silent. The following `catch` will catch errors that occur in either `then` callback, so be sure to extend it if necessary.

Apparently you have a variable `createdUser` that is not local to the second `then` callback, so you could use that to distinguish with other errors:

```
createdUser = null; // make sure to reset it (if not yet the case)
return formRef.current.isValid().then((isValid) => {
    if (!isValid) throw new Error("invalid"); // throw!
    return formatAndCreateUser(account);
}).then(createResponse => {
    createdUser = createResponse;
    return userApi.requestToken({email: account.email, password: account.password});
}).catch(err => {
    if (createdUser) throw err; // just bubble the error upwards
    // otherwise: do nothing (= ignore silently)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it conditionally, move it inside the `if` block:

```
return formRef.current.isValid()
.then((isValid) => {
    if (isValid) {
        return formatAndCreateUser(account)
        .then(createResponse => {
            createdUser = createResponse;
            return userApi.requestToken({email: account.email, password: account.password});
        });
    }
});
```

It's the same with `async`/`await`:

```
if (await formRef.current.isValid()) {
    createdUser = await formatAndCreateUser(account)
    await userApi.requestToken({email: account.email, password: account.password});
}
```

(Btw, try to avoid the global variable `createdUser`)